# r plotly subplot using more than 20 plots?

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I tried to create a subplot with big numbers. A simplified example: the following code which creates 19 empty plots works fine.

`plotList <- function(nplots) {
  lapply(seq_len(nplots), function(x) plot_ly())
}
subplot(plotList(19), nrows = 19, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)`

[image]
However, it goes wrong if the number of plots exceeds 20.

`subplot(plotList(21), nrows = 21, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)`

[image]
Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Have you ever heard of trelliscope? There might just be better ways to do lots of small multiples plots.

Comment: It looks like you took your example from [here](https://plot.ly/r/subplots/) so why not simply join multiple subplots as suggested in the example?

Comment: @be_green Thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: @MLavoie Thank you. Did you mean something like: `p1 <- subplot(plotList(19), nrows = 19, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
p2 <- subplot(plotList(2), nrows = 2, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
subplot(p1,p2)`
It still doesn’t work.

Comment: @Jinxi Liu what do you mean it does not work? For example, this works well: `p1 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE) 
p2 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE) 
p3 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE) 
p4 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE) 
p5 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE)
p6 <- subplot(plotList(5), nrows = 5, shareY = TRUE)
subplot(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6,  nrows = 6)`.

Comment: @MLavoie I tried `p7 <- subplot(plotList(19), nrows = 19, shareY = TRUE) 
p8 <- subplot(plotList(2), nrows = 2, shareY = TRUE) 
subplot(p7,p8,nrows=2)`. It doesn't produce right plot. Your code indeed works. This could be a solution. I guess the number of plots in each subplot should be small.